# One hour for what exactly?

Tags: harry-potter

At side ways elevator from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010), Yaxley speaks to Reginald:

> Yaxley: To interrogate your wife. Now, if my wife's blood status were
> in doubt...and the head of the Department of Magical Law
> Enforcement... needed a job doing, I think I might just make that a
> priority. You have **one hour**.

One hour for what exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To fix Yaxley's ceiling.**

> **YAXLEY:** It’s still raining in my office. Two days now.
>
> **REG CATTERMOLE/RON:** Really? Have you tried an umbrella?
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 1 - Official Screenplay](https://www.gazette-du-sorcier.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/pdf_Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows_-_Part_1.pdf)</sup></sub>